# Open a Toplevel by pressing a butten with functools.partial

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm openng a Toplevel window by pressing a butten with

```
command=lambda: PasswordWindow(self).grab_set()
```

but i want to use functools.partial to do this.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functools.partial` requires a callable, so you can't have it both create an instance of `PasswordWindow` and call a method on that object. You'll either need to move the call to `grab_set` inside `PasswordWindow.__init__`, or create a separate function that does what you want. Though, if you create a separate function, there's no need for `functools.partial`.